# How to pre filter a shared dataset?

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset published. It has a Customer dimension, Product dimension, and a Sales fact table.

I have created a one report for each customer by plugging into the shared dataset and applying the report level filter on customer name (customer dimension).

But my concern is that since the customer has build permission to the dataset and report, they can build their own reports and change the filter. How best to handle this?

Is there a way to create another dataset from the shared dataset with the Customer filter applied?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement RLS by applying the filter in the Customer dimension.

Or you create a Dataflow in Power BI Service to consume data from the shared dataset and there where you will be able to add the filters with the Dataflow query. (For this approach you need Power BI Premium or Premium Per User (PPU))

Know more about Power BI Dataflow :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-introduction-self-service

Comment: How about create a shared dataset, and then another shared dataset from this and filter on one customer and then expose that as a shared dataset to customer?

Comment: I don't think Power BI support creating a shared dataset directly from another shared dataset.